# HTML change color of form elements

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to make the text inside the select form have colors so example where you write your name to send email i want the text is a color black example, Also inside the select form i tried using div but failed to get it to work. I tried putting this in the css also to link it to div also didn't

```
work.
#skills  {
color:F0F8FF;
}


<form name="enq" method="post" action="email/" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <fieldset class="contact-inner">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <input type="text" id="email" value="" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="name" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name." autofocus>
        <input type="text" id="skype" value="" name="skype" placeholder="Your Skype Name." autofocus>
      </p>

      <div id="skills">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="why" id="why">      
            <option value="" selected>Skills</option>
            <option value="3D Printing">3D Printing</option>
            <option value="Alternative Healers">Alternative Healers</option>
            <option value="Aquaponics/Hydroponics">Aquaponics/Hydroponics</option>
            <option value="Architecture/Design">Architecture/Design</option>
            <option value="Cabinetry / Carpentry">Cabinetry / Carpentry</option>
            <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
            <option value="Culinary Arts">Culinary Arts</option>
            <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
            <option value="EM Technology">EM Technology</option>
            <option value="Free Energy/QEG">Free Energy/QEG</option>
            <option value="Hair and/or Nail Stylist">Hair and/or Nail Stylist</option>
            <option value="Hemp Farming">Hemp Farming</option>
            <option value="Hempcrete">Hempcrete</option>
            <option value="Kundalini8 Practitioner">Kundalini8 Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
            <option value="Massage Therapist">Massage Therapist</option>
            <option value="Qi Gong Practitioners">Qi Gong Practitioners</option>
            <option value="Permaculture">Permaculture</option>
            <option value="Recycling">Recycling</option>
            <option value="Sewing">Sewing</option>
            <option value="Tai Chi Practitioner">Tai Chi Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>
            </div>

          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="participate" id="participate">
            <option value="" selected>When can you participate?</option>
            <option value="3-6 months from now">3-6 months from now</option>
            <option value="6-12 months">6-12 months</option>
            <option value="Next Year (2016)">Next Year (2016)</option>
            <option value="Don't know yet">Don't know yet</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-input">
        <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message…"></textarea>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
-input-placeholder
```

Is this what you wanted?

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #000;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #000;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #000;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   color:    #000;
}
```

```html
<form name="enq" method="post" action="email/" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <fieldset class="contact-inner">
         <p class="contact-input">
          <input type="text" id="email" value="" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..." autofocus />
            <input type="text" id="name" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name." autofocus />
            <input type="text" id="skype" value="" name="skype" placeholder="Your Skype Name." autofocus />
            </p>
      <div id="skills">
      
          <label for="select" class="select"></label>
          <select name="why" id="why">      
            <option value="" selected>Skills</option>
            <option value="3D Printing">3D Printing</option>
            <option value="Alternative Healers">Alternative Healers</option>
            <option value="Aquaponics/Hydroponics">Aquaponics/Hydroponics</option>
            <option value="Architecture/Design">Architecture/Design</option>
            <option value="Cabinetry / Carpentry">Cabinetry / Carpentry</option>
            <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
            <option value="Culinary Arts">Culinary Arts</option>
            <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
            <option value="EM Technology">EM Technology</option>
            <option value="Free Energy/QEG">Free Energy/QEG</option>
            <option value="Hair and/or Nail Stylist">Hair and/or Nail Stylist</option>
            <option value="Hemp Farming">Hemp Farming</option>
            <option value="Hempcrete">Hempcrete</option>
            <option value="Kundalini8 Practitioner">Kundalini8 Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
            <option value="Massage Therapist">Massage Therapist</option>
            <option value="Qi Gong Practitioners">Qi Gong Practitioners</option>
            <option value="Permaculture">Permaculture</option>
            <option value="Recycling">Recycling</option>
            <option value="Sewing">Sewing</option>
            <option value="Tai Chi Practitioner">Tai Chi Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>

          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select"></label>
          <select name="participate" id="participate">
            <option value="" selected>When can you participate?</option>
            <option value="3-6 months from now">3-6 months from now</option>
            <option value="6-12 months">6-12 months</option>
            <option value="Next Year (2016)">Next Year (2016)</option>
            <option value="Don't know yet">Don't know yet</option>
          </select>
         </div>
          </p>

      <p class="contact-input">
        <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message…"></textarea>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: i used your code it puts the email name all on the same line ?? and makes the text box black i want it white and the text to be purple

Comment: Yeah, the code will then work because it targets all input tags.

Comment: i want it like this like before but just the text purple [img]http://i.imgur.com/GYlaFbV.png[/img] now it looks like this [img]http://i.imgur.com/7u7sl36.png[/img]

Comment: Don't Copy my HTML, I made some edits by accident and couldn't figure out where they went. Copy your HTML from the OP, and continue using my CSS I posted. My CSS should not change the position of anything, it only touches the placeholder text of an input field.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```css
#email {
    color:blue; /*target element with id email and set text color to blue*/
}
#name {
    color: red; /*target element with id name and set text color to red*/
}
#skype {
    color: green; /*target element with id skype and set text color to green*/
}
#why {
    color: orange; /*target element with id why and set text color to orange. in this case, its a select, so all the text within the select - meaning the options text- is orange*/
}
#participate .yellow {
    color: yellow;    /*target elements with class yellow (options) inside element id participate (select)  and set text color to yellow. in this case, you can select which options to make yellow by adding classes*/
}
#message {
    color: purple; /*target element with id message and set text color to purple*/
}
```

```html
<form name="enq" method="post" action="email/" onsubmit="return validation();">
  <fieldset class="contact-inner">
    <p class="contact-input">
      <input type="text" id="email" value="aaaa" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..." autofocus>
      <input type="text" id="name" value="bbbbb" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name." autofocus>
      <input type="text" id="skype" value="cccc" name="skype" placeholder="Your Skype Name." autofocus>
    </p>

    <div id="skills">
      <p class="contact-input">
        <label for="select" class="select">
          <select name="why" id="why">      
            <option value="" selected>Skills</option>
            <option value="3D Printing">3D Printing</option>
            <option value="Alternative Healers">Alternative Healers</option>
            <option value="Aquaponics/Hydroponics">Aquaponics/Hydroponics</option>
            <option value="Architecture/Design">Architecture/Design</option>
            <option value="Cabinetry / Carpentry">Cabinetry / Carpentry</option>
            <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
            <option value="Culinary Arts">Culinary Arts</option>
            <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
            <option value="EM Technology">EM Technology</option>
            <option value="Free Energy/QEG">Free Energy/QEG</option>
            <option value="Hair and/or Nail Stylist">Hair and/or Nail Stylist</option>
            <option value="Hemp Farming">Hemp Farming</option>
            <option value="Hempcrete">Hempcrete</option>
            <option value="Kundalini8 Practitioner">Kundalini8 Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
            <option value="Massage Therapist">Massage Therapist</option>
            <option value="Qi Gong Practitioners">Qi Gong Practitioners</option>
            <option value="Permaculture">Permaculture</option>
            <option value="Recycling">Recycling</option>
            <option value="Sewing">Sewing</option>
            <option value="Tai Chi Practitioner">Tai Chi Practitioner</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>


          </select>
          <label for="select" class="select">
            <select name="participate" id="participate">
              <option value="" selected>When can you participate?</option>
              <option value="3-6 months from now">3-6 months from now</option>
              <option class="yellow" value="6-12 months">6-12 months</option>
              <option value="Next Year (2016)">Next Year (2016)</option>
              <option class="yellow" value="Don't know yet">Don't know yet</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="contact-input">
      <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message…">ddddd</textarea>
    </p>

    <p class="contact-submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I think he meant he wanted the example text(placeholder) to be of the color black.